# Java Script Condition Statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I want to add a condition to my JavaScript code, where if I write the correct answer in the text box it will go to the next page.

For example: the question is: "What is the capital of Japan?", if I write Tokyo it will go to a new page, but if write the wrong answer it will just show the alert box message.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function nameValidate() {
            valid = true;
            if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
                alert("Please enter the right answer");
                valid = false;
            }
            return valid;
        }
    </script>

    <title>Crack the code</title>
</head>
<body text="#666633" bgcolor="#cccc99">
    <div align="center">
        <p class="text">
            <h3>What is the Capital of Japan</h3>
        </p>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"></td>
                <form name="Answer" action="http://news.google.com/" onsubmit="return nameValidate();">
                    <input type="text" id="name" />
                    </td>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="Submit" value="submit" />
                </form>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="8"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your if condition will not meet your requirements if you fill Dhaka for the capital city of Japan! So correct this first.

Comment: can you help me correct the above code please.

Comment: The closing `</td>` tag after `<input id="name">` is irritating me... Or better, why is the `<form>` tag directly inside the `<tr>`?

Comment: See the answer now that is given by me! and let me know if you need anything more. Also please accept this answer if you feel that it is correct for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition just checks whether your input text is empty or not. If you want to make sure the answer is Tokyo you can use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nameValidate(){
       var myInput = document.getElementById('name').value.toLowerCase();
       var valid = true;
       if(myInput != "tokyo"){
          alert("Please enter the right answer");
          valid = false;
       }
     return valid;
   }
</script>
```

I use the `toLowerCase` function to ensure that any possible answer will be accepted.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer but your code is only working in Google Chrome when i try to open it in fire fox and IE it is not working.

Comment: which part of my code doesn't work! it's just a simple javascript code  I checked my code again actually there was a bug there but I edit my answer.Test it again hope that should help :)

Comment: when i test in chrome and firefox the code works perfectly, but when i open it in IE and i type the wrong answers it still go in to the website or even if i leave it black and enter, it still go to the link that i put.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct except the scenario if the user input something different than you are expecting. You doesn't notice anything because your form submission goes to google and this also prevent by google somehow! So this make you wrong! Please change your form submission like

```
action="http://naimrajib.blogspot.com/"
```

Also change your code like this:

```
function nameValidate()
{
    var answer = {japan: 'tokyo', bangladesh: 'dhaka'}
    var valid = true;
    var input_value = document.getElementById('name').value.toLowerCase();

   if (input_value == null  || input_value == "") {
       alert("Please enter the right answer");
       valid = false;
   }
   else if(input_value == answer.japan){
       valid = true;
  }
  else
       valid = false;

  alert(valid);
return valid;
}
```

To see the demonstration, Visit this link: http://jsfiddle.net/naimrajib/5Lzt7opg/